# How to pass a link into a custom Action

Tags: c#, installation, session-variables, custom-action, wix3.11

currently I have define a Custom Action where I am validating whether a client machine has .net 6 installed or not and a appropriate message I am passing through session message. like below.

```
 string downloadLink = "<a href=\"https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0\">https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0</a>";
 string errorMessage = $"This setup requires Microsoft .NET 6.0.16 SDK. Download the SDK from {downloadLink}";

 session.Message(InstallMessage.Error, new Record { FormatString = errorMessage });
```

and the above message displaying in `InstallExecuteSequence` like below.

```
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
 <Custom Action="_CA_CheckNETCoreVersion" Before="FindRelatedProducts">
      <![CDATA[NETCORE = "NO"]]>
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>.
```

but the download link what i provied it is coming as normal text like below image
[image]

please help me how can I make the above link as clickable

Comment: Have you got an example of a vanilla pop up which does have a working link in it?
Usually I have to ctrl+c on the window to get the text.

Comment: @DisplayName ,is vanilla pop up not belongs  to  wix , can you please provide me some example , or is there any way we can directly provide the link in Session.message ?

Comment: Ah I see - can you update your question to reference the libaries you are using? It's only mentioned in the tags as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hi @DisplayName , i have updated the question by the namespace that  I have taken ,please let me know if you need any additional information , Actually I am little new to the Wix .so can you give me any example where can I make a text to a clickable link